# New column indicating preference by calculating conditional probability in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe of race data of athletes that looks like the following:

```
Race_ID  Athlete_ID  Distance  Rank
1        1           100       3
2        1           400       6
3        1           1500      1
4        1           100       6
5        1           100       1
6        1           1500      1
7        2           100       1
8        2           400       2
9        2           400       1
10       2           1500      6
11       2           1500      4
12       2           100       1
13       2           100       1
```

and I want to make a new column called `Dist_Preference` to see what distance (100 (short), 400 (middle), 1500 (long)) the athlete is more good at by calculating the conditional probability of the athlete of winning that distance. So for example:

P(athlete 1 winning a 100m race | it is a 100m race) = 2/3

P(athlete 1 winning a 400m race | it is a 400m race) = 0/1 = 0

P(athlete 1 winning a 1500m race | it is a 1500m race) = 2/2 = 1

Hence athlete 1 clearly has a preference of running long distance.
and so fourth, and the desired column looks like

```
Race_ID  Athlete_ID  Distance  Rank  Dist_Preference
1        1           100       3     1500
2        1           400       6     1500     
3        1           1500      1     1500
4        1           100       6     1500
5        1           100       1     1500
6        1           1500      1     1500
7        2           100       1     100
8        2           400       2     100
9        2           400       1     100
10       2           1500      6     100
11       2           1500      4     100
12       2           100       1     100
13       2           100       1     100
```

I have written a subroutine to do this by defining a method that calculates the conditional probabilities as above and then use `.apply` but it is incredibly slow for large dataframe, I wonder if there is any quick way to do this.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean column: `win` to identify the winning races, then pivot the dataframe with aggfunc `mean` which will calculate the probabilities, then use `idxmax` to find the preferred distance based on winning probability

```
df['win'] = df['Rank'] == 1
prob = df.pivot_table('win', 'Athlete_ID', 'Distance')
df['preferred_dist'] = df['Athlete_ID'].map(prob.idxmax(1))
```

Result

```
    Race_ID  Athlete_ID  Distance  Rank    win  preferred_dist
0         1           1       100     3  False            1500
1         2           1       400     6  False            1500
2         3           1      1500     1   True            1500
3         4           1       100     6  False            1500
4         5           1       100     1   True            1500
5         6           1      1500     1   True            1500
6         7           2       100     1   True             100
7         8           2       400     2  False             100
8         9           2       400     1   True             100
9        10           2      1500     6  False             100
10       11           2      1500     4  False             100
11       12           2       100     1   True             100
12       13           2       100     1   True             100
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df
Race_ID  Athlete_ID  Distance  Rank
1        1           100       3
2        1           400       6
3        1           1500      1
4        1           100       6
5        1           100       1
6        1           1500      1
7        2           100       1
8        2           400       2
9        2           400       1
10       2           1500      6
11       2           1500      4
12       2           100       1
13       2           100       1

df1 = df.groupby(['Athlete_ID', 'Distance']).agg(nbr_of_races=('Rank', lambda x: len(x)),
     nbr_of_races_won=('Rank', lambda x: len([i for i in x if i == 1]))).reset_index()

df1['performance'] = (df1['nbr_of_races_won']*100/df1['nbr_of_races']).round(2)

df1
    Athlete_ID  Distance    nbr_of_races    nbr_of_races_won    performance
0   1           100         3               1                   33.33
1   1           400         1               0                   0.00
2   1           1500        2               2                   100.00
3   2           100         3               3                   100.00
4   2           400         2               1                   50.00
5   2           1500        2               0                   0.00

#sort by performance
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Athlete_ID', 'performance'], ascending=[True, False])

    Athlete_ID  Distance    nbr_of_races    nbr_of_races_won    performance
2   1           1500        2               2                   100.00
0   1           100         3               1                   33.33
1   1           400         1               0                   0.00
3   2           100         3               3                   100.00
4   2           400         2               1                   50.00
5   2           1500        2               0                   0.00

#keep only the best performed Distance for each Athlete
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('Athlete_ID') 

    Athlete_ID  Distance    nbr_of_races    nbr_of_races_won    performance
2   1           1500        2               2                   100.0
3   2           100         3               3                   100.0

#merge 
df = df.merge(df1.loc[:, ['Athlete_ID', 'Distance']].rename(columns={"Distance": "preferred_dist"}), on='Athlete_ID', how='left')

df

    Race_ID Athlete_ID  Distance    Rank    preferred_dist
0   1       1           100         3       1500
1   2       1           400         6       1500
2   3       1           1500        1       1500
3   4       1           100         6       1500
4   5       1           100         1       1500
5   6       1           1500        1       1500
6   7       2           100         1       100
7   8       2           400         2       100
8   9       2           400         1       100
9   10      2           1500        6       100
10  11      2           1500        4       100
11  12      2           100         1       100
12  13      2           100         1       100
```